# Remove right click table arrows firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

[image]

I'm trying to create a context menu for tables using javascript and bootstrap, but when I right click on a table that's in an editable div, I get some arrows that allow the user to add some new rows and columns. Is there anyway to remove them ?

**I'm using Firefox**

Thank you very much.

Update: link to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/toby3105/LSyC8/7/

```
<div id="context" data-toggle="context" data-target="#context-menu" contenteditable="true">
            <table border="1">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

I don't think is has anything to do with bootstrap, i think i only has to do with Firefox. The z-index is 15000.

Comment: Could you please supply a link to the live site, or better yet create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Checking http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#tables can't find that feature. Where are you seeing it?

Comment: @Evan created the fiddle and updated the post. Ivo Pereira and dfsq i don't think it has anything to do with bootstrap. This only happens in firefox.

Comment: Quickly fired up firefox to experience this feature, ..., disappointed :(

Comment: This does not work at all in Chrome.

Comment: @Ejay i don't really understand when you right click don't you get those handles to be able to resize the table and add/remove new columns/rows ?

Comment: I only see handles, no menu. May be I misunderstood your question?

Comment: When I use FF and right-click a cell, I see the handles but not the context menu. Version issue? (I'm using the latest) However, it seems that those handles allow addition of new cells. Is there a config option to disable adding new rows/columns?

Comment: In FF 20.0.1 I get the handles whether right or left clicking.

Comment: I'm really sorry everyone i've updated the link to the fiddle. The problem isn't the menu it's the handles i want to get rid of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this does the trick.

```
document.designMode = "on";
document.execCommand("enableObjectResizing", false, "false");
document.execCommand("enableInlineTableEditing", false, "false");
```

Comment: +1 Found something close to this, but wasn't comprehensive enough to work. Nice find.